# Find two firstnames in a database as part of full name column

Tags: mysql

Yo.

I want to find two first names such as 'name1' 'name2' in a column which contains both firstname and lastname.

WHERE ContactName IN ('name1%', 'name2%'); <-- doesn't work with wildcards

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
where Match(ContactName ) Against ('name1', 'name2')
```

but before that make sure that you have Full text Index created on name field.

Comment: This is likely to be faster, once the full text index is built, than multiple like clauses and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to list each individually and use `LIKE`

```
WHERE ContactName LIKE 'name1 %' OR ContactName LIKE 'name2 %';
```

Note that I've added a space after the name. I assumed you want an exact match on the first name.

Alternatively you could use MySQL [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) function:

```
WHERE ContactName REGEXP '^(name1|name2)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE ContactName LIKE "name1%" OR ContactName LIKE "name2%";
```

Comment: I would do '%name1%' and '%name2%' ... that ensure that their order can be change in name.

Comment: Oh right yeah. Thought so. What's the need for IN then? Just to simplify searching for exact values?

Comment: @SumitGupta - and I'd strongly recommend **NOT** to put **%** at the beginning of the string. That would simply make the index useless.

Comment: Agree, but in your query than it will find all name that contain either name1 and name2 that start WITH either name1 or name2, but if it doesn't it won't get found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name 
        WHERE ContactName LIKE "name1%" OR ContactName LIKE "name2%";
```

Comment: % at the beginning of the string is always a bad idea. Read further about indexes.

Answer (score 0):

***you should refer this link [CLICK HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_wildcard_percent):***

```
.......WHERE ContactName LIKE 'name1 %' OR ContactName LIKE 'name2 %';
```